# How to batch collection by property, recursively

Tags: linq, parallel-processing

I’m trying to come up with an algorithm that given a collection of objects with children and "AlarmCount" property would split the collection into balanced batches to be processed in parallel.

For example:

```
    public class AlarmElement
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<AlarmElement> Children { get; set; }
       public int AlarmCount { get; set; }
    }

    var list = new List<AlarmElement>();
    list.Add(new AlarmElement { Id = 1, AlarmCount = 10, Children = new List<AlarmElement> { new AlarmElement { AlarmCount = 10 } } });
    list.Add(new AlarmElement { Id = 2, AlarmCount = 5, Children = new List<AlarmElement> { new AlarmElement { AlarmCount = 5 } } });
    list.Add(new AlarmElement { Id = 3, AlarmCount = 5, Children = new List<AlarmElement> { new AlarmElement { AlarmCount = 5 } } });
```

The function would return 2 collections, one with AlarmElement 1 (20 Alarms) and the other with AlarmElement 2 and 3 (20 Alarms).

Any ideas on the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice problem :)

I've wrote a starter solution for this problem by splitting the first list into 2 lists each has total amount close to the other.

```
    public class AlarmElement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AlarmElement> Children { get; set; }
        public int AlarmCount { get; set; }
    }

    class Grouped
    {
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public AlarmElement Alarm { get; set; }
    }

    int Count(AlarmElement element)
    {
        if (element == null) return 0;

        return element.AlarmCount + Count(element.Children);
    }

    int Count(IEnumerable<AlarmElement> elements)
    {
        if (elements == null || elements.Count() == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int count = 0;

        foreach (AlarmElement alarm in elements)
        {
            count += Count(alarm);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

So those just a helper class and 2 methods for counting each AlarmElement childrens.

The Split method takes a collection and it's average and just splits it into 2 collections around that average:

```
    private void Split(IEnumerable<Grouped> alarms, double avg, 
        out IEnumerable<AlarmElement> firstAlarms, 
        out IEnumerable<AlarmElement> secondAlarms)
    {
        firstAlarms = 
            alarms
            .Where(a => a.Total < avg)
            .Select(a => a.Alarm);

        secondAlarms =
             alarms
            .Where(a => a.Total > avg)
            .Select(a => a.Alarm);
    }
```

This is your entry point where you send your initial list of alarms:

```
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<AlarmElement>> GetBalanced(List<AlarmElement> list)
    {            
        var alarms =
            list
            .Select(a => new Grouped { Total = Count(a), Alarm = a });

        var avg = alarms.Average(a => a.Total);

        var result = new List<IEnumerable<AlarmElement>>();

        IEnumerable<AlarmElement> firstAlarms;               

        IEnumerable<AlarmElement> secondAlarms;

        Split(alarms, avg, out firstAlarms, out secondAlarms);

        result.Add(firstAlarms);
        result.Add(secondAlarms);

        return result;
    }
```

As I mentioned, it's just a starter because you can further enhance it by using the Split method recursively on each part until you're satisfied.